# replace form input file with direct file upload

Tags: php, curl, upload

I'm working on a serverside Youtube uploader in php. Using [this script](http://rubensargsyan.com/generate-youtube-video-browser-based-uploading-form-by-php/) I upload the video file successfully to Youtube. However, I don't want to manually select the file, but I want to upload a file that is already on my server. 
I know the filename/-path (and have the video base64-coded likewise if this was helpful in any way), and I have all keys and tokens that are needed for Youtube. However, I don't know how to transform all this information into the appropriate http-post.

```
<form action="<?php echo($response->url); ?>?nexturl=<?php echo(urlencode($nexturl)); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo($response->token); ?>"/>
   <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

I already tried my best to digg deeper into cURL, but I'm not sure if this is what will help me here.

Comment: I would still suggest using curl, I think is your best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the script found at the url you  provided I would try this first:

```
$ch = curl_init($response->url."?nexturl=".urlencode($nexturl));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array(
    "file"=>"@/path/to/file.avi",
    "token"=>$response->token
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```