# curl response for youtube upload

Tags: php, curl

I have another question concerning YouTube upload. Based on the answer that I received from khael here ([replace form input file with direct file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918115/replace-form-input-file-with-direct-file-upload)), the script uploads the video perfectly. However, the curl response is "Moved Temporarily". What I need instead is to get the YouTube video ID back.

Another problem is that the "nexturl" never gets called. If it was called, I could easily read the video id with "$_GET['id']" and write it to the database.

Here the code I'm working with

```
$ch = curl_init($response->url."?nexturl=".urlencode($nexturl));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array(
   "file"=>"@/path/to/file.avi",
   "token"=>$response->token
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing I'd guess that if you add the FOLLOWLOCATION option you'd get what you're after:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```